# Zfs Replace - How to remove drives after replaced

Tags: zfs

I have a zfs Z2 (Raid 6 equivalent array) comprising 8 1Tb drives, that previously had been working well for a couple of years.

Due to disk problems, I have had to replace at first one drive, then another.
I added extra drives with the command "zpool replace -f zpool2 sda sdi".

I have other 1Tb drives (sdi, sdk) in the workstation that are connected via an alternative controller.

The Resilvering has completed, but the drive has not changed its status from DEGRADED, and I also cannot remove the drives from the array using remove or offline commands.

Whilst I have a backup, I did not want to have to re-create the array.  Can I just switch the machine off and remove the offending disks.  Did I do something wrong so that the vdev are now fixed permanently to this array rather than being replacements?
[image]
Array Status after Desilvering/replacements
[image]
Failed remove and offline commands.

I understand zfs apparently has problems removing drives, is this an example?

Can I just remove the offending drives without losing data?
I know I should have used better labels, but when I started with zfs a few years ago I didn't know this.